# Java8 - get by index but something similar to 'getOrDefault' for Map?

Tags: collections, java-8, option-type

Is there a cleaner way to check whether a value is present at a particular index like `list.getOrDefault(index, "defaultValue")`.  Or even do a default operation when the particular index is out of range of the list.

The normal way to do this is to check for size of the list before attempting this operation.

Comment: If you haven't found it in the javadoc of List, then there is none.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface does not have this functionality. There is `Iterables.get` in [Guava](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#get-java.lang.Iterable-int-T-):

```
Iterables.get(iterable, position, defaultValue);
```

> Returns the element at the specified position in `iterable` or
> `defaultValue` if `iterable` contains fewer than `position + 1` elements.
>
> Throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `position` is negative.

If this is functionality you intend to use a lot and can't afford to depend on third-party libraries, you could write your own static method (here inspired by the Guava [`Lists`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) class):

```
public class Lists {

  public static <E> E getOrDefault(int index, E defaultValue, List<E> list) {
    if (index < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("index is less than 0: " + index);
    }
    return index <= list.size() - 1 ? list.get(index) : defaultValue;
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is not totally correct… While I (still) couldn't find an appropriate method in Commons Collections, there IS a method in Guava, that will serve that purpose. It's called [Iterables.get](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#get-java.lang.Iterable-int-T-)

Comment: stream could be used:
list.stream().skip(<index>).findFirst().orElse(<default value>)